# Is it possible to make one of two custom fields in Custom Post Type UI Required but not the other?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, pages

I'm new to wordpress and I'm trying to make a field that either links to a page internally via a dropdown OR a text area for a URL. Obviously I don't want the button to have two destinations so I'd like to make them both required but only one can have a value at a given time. Is this possible in CPT UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/). If I understand what you want to do correctly, you can add a [Select Field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/select/) with Radio Buttons, and then build conditional Page Link and Text (for the URL) Fields that appear based on the Select Field button.

You would then build an if/else statement in the code:

```
<?php if(get_field('page_link') == "internal"): ?>
  <a href="<?php the_field('internal_page_link'); ?>">Page Link</a>
<?php else: ?>
  <a href="<?php get_field('external_page_link'); ?>">Page Link</a>  
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can set the two options up to be conditional based on the selected button from select field.

Also note in this example, you should use `get_field` for the Text field. This will return it as a string and not output text to html.